# Webpack: ExtractTextPlugin: Not to generate separate empty JS file when have several css entry points?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin

I have several CSS entry points:

```
entry: {
  ...
  styles: [
    ...
  ],
  fonts: [
    ...
  ]
},
```

and I'm using ExtractTextPlugin to bundle CSS separately:

```
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: `[name].bundle.css`
  }),
```

So like output I have 2 CSS files: **styles.css** and **fonts.css** that is correct but also empty **styles.js** and **fonts.js**. Is there a way to not generate empty JS files?

Answer (score 3):

I put together a [webpack plugin](https://github.com/AnujRNair/webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin) to remove extra files based on their final output size as I had the same issue - given these files tend to be very small, it seems to just be a case of checking how large they are and removing the small, useless ones.

Install using `npm` or `yarn`

```
npm install webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin --save-dev
yarn add webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin --dev
```

In your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin = require('webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ExtraneousFileCleanupPlugin({
      extensions: ['.js']
    })
  ]
}
```

You can see the full list of options on the [Webpack Extraneous File Cleanup Plugin Github Page](https://github.com/AnujRNair/webpack-extraneous-file-cleanup-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

### Only add the main javascript files as entries and require all fonts and style via `require('./style.css')`

**webpack.config.js:**

```
entry: {
  'main': 'app/main',
},
output: {
  path: 'static',
  publicPath: '/static/',
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].bundle.js',
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader'
      }),
    }]
},
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].bundle.css'),
],
```

That would give you a `/static/main.bundle.css` with all css (transitively) included from your app/main.js.

Same for fonts, but you would need a second ExtractTextPlugin instance like:

```
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name].bundle.css');
const extractFonts = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name].bundle.woff');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff$/i,
        use: extractFonts.extract([ 'url-loader' ])
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    extractFonts
  ]
};
```

See the [Documentation - Multiple Instances](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#multiple-instances) for more info about that.

Comment: But I would like to make the spit not based on rules. 
I have fonts.scss and styles.scss like an entry points.

Comment: Avoiding rules entirely won't work. If it's just about those two entry points and only one Javascript entry point, you will just have to rename those css and font links, remove their entry points and add those extractors. Give it a try, it works like a charm for us 

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to do what you are trying to do, [the same question has been asked on the github issue tracker](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1967), without any solution. If the problem is with the **html-webpack-plugin** adding the empty js files, you should be able to fix that by [explicitly specifying what chunks to include or exclude](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#filtering-chunks).

Comment: yes, I tried this approach, but unfortunately if you put fonts into exclude there is no CSS file as well :(